# Why would I NOT want to use static controllers?

Tags: visualforce, controller, heap, static

For starters, using static variables/methods resolves view state issues. I don't seem to notice any difference in VF behaviour when using static versus non-static methods either. So when would I use which?

Obviously there is impact on heap size but I think the 6MB limit is more than enough for almost all use cases that require VF page.

Comment: Given that a static variable is scoped only to the execution context (as opposed to the lifetime of the application), I don't see a big issue in using static members. However, they don't seem the right tool for the job. If you want to reduce your viewstate size (I assume that is the 'issue' you're talking about), that's what the transient keyword was designed for.

Comment: The `transient` keyword doesn't preserve the state of the variable. That is one major limitation in comparison to making them static.

Answer (score 1):

There can be lots of scenario where you static variables and methods may not be useful. to begin with, static cannot give you the referencing for obvious reasons,

Some features of static variables in Apex (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)-

1. They’re associated with a class.
2. They’re allowed only in outer classes.
3. They’re initialized only when a class is loaded.
4. They aren’t transmitted as part of the view state for a Visualforce page.

So even if you use static then you cannot even pass it using Viewstate, which makes it pretty much useless (confirming on your fact that it is not part of view state).

For instance variables -

1. They’re associated with a particular object.
2. They have no definition modifier.
3. They’re created with every object instantiated from the class in which they’re declared.

So that is generally for utility methods etc we use static keyword as we want that functionality to be agnostic.

hope this all helps :)

Ray

Comment: I can't pass it to the page using viewstate, but I can pass it via the memory. I don't see any of the above points as reasons for not wanting to use static variables in a controller. Controllers don't need to be instantiated as objects (other than by their page of course, which is a one time deal).

Comment: you can pass it using memory possibly by making some remote call outs but there are multiple scenarios where you may want to render stuff rather than going the route of using memory and dynamic DOM manipulations which will be much more complicated in coparison.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I follow. Maybe you are confusing static methods/variables with JS Remoting? Or maybe with webservices? I don't need to use any remote calls to call a static method from the controller..